# Prove that a group is dense in an interval

Tags: group-theory, induction

I tried many ways to solve it and I think it is supposed to be solved using induction, but I seem to get stuck at the very beginning of the induction. I'd like to hear your suggestions of ways to solve it.

[image]

Thank you!

Comment: Are these *additive* groups?

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HINT: Suppose that $x,y\in(0,1)$ with $x<y$. Choose any $a\in A$ such that $a>1$.

- Explain why there is a positive integer $n$ such that $\frac{a}n<y-x$.
- Show that for each $k\in\Bbb Z^+$, $\frac{ka}n\in B$.
- Show that there must be a $k\in\Bbb Z^+$ such that $x<\frac{ka}n<y$.

Comment: Thank you. is it enough to find one element of B between x and y to prove  that it is dense in interval (0,1)?

Comment: @Yakirbu: Not quite: this just shows that $B$ is dense in itself (because I misread the question and thought that that’s what was wanted). Give me a few minutes, and I’ll revise it appropriately.

Comment: @Yakirbu: Okay, it’s fixed now; in some ways this may even be a little easier.

Comment: Thank you, definitely what I was looking for.
Just one last question though;
What you said in the 2 last points is related only to the first point, right? otherwise it won't be true, for example (k = n).

Comment: @Yakirbu: You’re welcome. Yes, the $n$ of the last two points is the one whose existence is established in the first point.